# C# Add item to ObjectListView

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

My program extracts Windows Updates, detects the version numbers and logs them to columns (KB, Version) in a list view, but I'm trying to change this to an [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/) so I can sort the columns. I can't for the life of me work out how to write the results to an ObjectListView and nothing I try seems to work. Here's my current code:

```
foreach (string file in msu)
{
    string KB = GetKBNumber(file);
    Expand.MSU(file, TempDirectory + "\\" + KB);
    List<string> versions = GetVersionNumbers(TempDirectory + "\\" + KB);

    foreach (string version in versions)
    {
        ListViewItem itm = new ListViewItem(new[] { KB, version });
        olvOutput.Items.Add(itm);
    }
    PerformStep();
}
```

But it just writes blank data to the control. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here's the olvOutput designer code:

```
        // 
        // olvOutput
        // 
        this.olvOutput.AllColumns.Add(this.olvKBNumber);
        this.olvOutput.AllColumns.Add(this.olvVersion);
        this.olvOutput.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.olvOutput.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
        this.olvKBNumber,
        this.olvVersion});
        this.olvOutput.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(18, 12);
        this.olvOutput.Name = "olvOutput";
        this.olvOutput.ShowGroups = false;
        this.olvOutput.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(571, 193);
        this.olvOutput.TabIndex = 8;
        this.olvOutput.UseAlternatingBackColors = true;
        this.olvOutput.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.olvOutput.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
        // 
        // olvKBNumber
        // 
        this.olvKBNumber.AspectName = "";
        this.olvKBNumber.CellPadding = null;
        this.olvKBNumber.MaximumWidth = 100;
        this.olvKBNumber.MinimumWidth = 100;
        this.olvKBNumber.Text = "KB Number";
        this.olvKBNumber.Width = 100;
        // 
        // olvVersion
        // 
        this.olvVersion.AspectName = "";
        this.olvVersion.CellPadding = null;
        this.olvVersion.Text = "Version";
        this.olvVersion.Width = 113;
```

Comment: Could you provide a code where you are creating and setting up the `olvOutput` ?

Comment: And the Properties of the control would be nice.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've edited my post to include the designer code.

Comment: The answer from Michal is fine. In general, if you find yourself messing with a ListViewItem, you are probably doing it wrong. You never have to manually modify a ListViewItem when working with an OLV. Re-read the documentation, its pretty good.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll give it another read now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify the first of your snippets as:

```
foreach (string file in msu)
{
    string KB = GetKBNumber(file);
    Expand.MSU(file, TempDirectory + "\\" + KB);
    List<string> versions = GetVersionNumbers(TempDirectory + "\\" + KB);

    foreach (string version in versions)
    {
        olvOutput.AddObject(new { kbAspectName = KB, versionAspectName = version });
    }
    PerformStep();
}
```

... and modify the second code snippet as:

```
// 
// olvKBNumber
// 
this.olvKBNumber.AspectName = "kbAspectName";

// ...

// 
// olvVersion
// 
this.olvVersion.AspectName = "versionAspectName";
```

**Disclaimer:**
never worked with `ObjectListView` before so I am not saying this is the best way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Sorry, as you can probably guess I'm still new here. I've accepted the answer but I wasn't able to upvote as I don't have enough reputation - sorry!